# String similarity in c

Tags: c, suffix-array

For two strings A and B, we define the similarity of the strings to be the length of the longest prefix common to both strings. For example, the similarity of strings "abc" and "abd" is 2, while the similarity of strings "aaa" and "aaab" is 3.
Calculate the sum of similarities of a string S with each of its suffixes

Here is my solution...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int getSim(char str[],int subindex)
{
    int l2=subindex
    int i=0;
    int count=0;
    for(i=0;i<l2;i++)
        if(str[i]==str[subindex])
        {
            count++;
            subindex++;
        }
        else
            break;
    return count;   
}
int main()
{
    int testcase=0;
    int len=0;
    int sum=0;
    int i=0;
    char s[100000];
    scanf("%d",&testcase);
    while(testcase--)
    {
        sum=0;
        scanf("%s",s);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
            if(s[i]==s[0])
            {
                sum=sum+getSim(s,i);
            }
        printf("%d\n",sum);
    }
}
```

How can we go about solving this problem using suffix array??

Comment: What is the output of your program that you feel is incorrect? If you're looking for a code review, try codereview.stackexchange... StackOverflow is for where you have a specific question you need answered.

Comment: why do you speak of a suffix array? Shouldn't that be a *prefix* ?

Comment: @glowcoder nothing is wrong with the output of my program....but it a bit slow when the input size increases..say 100000 length string....so some one suggested using a suffix array.....

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it is the best algorithm, but here is the solution.

First of all, build suffix array. The naive algorithm(putting all suffixes into array and then sorting it) is quite slow - O(n^2 * log(n)) operations, there are several algorithms to do this in O(nlogn) time.

I'm assuming that strings are 0-indexed.

1. Now, take the first letter `l` in the string `s`, and use one binary search to find the index `i` of the first string in the suffix array which starts with `l`, and another binary search to find the index `j` of the first string in range [i..n], which doesn't start with `l`. Then you'll have that all strings in the range [i..j-1] starts with the same letter `l`. So the answer to the problem is at least j-i.
2. Then apply similar procedure to the strings in range [i..j). Take the second letter `l2`, find indexes `i2` and `j2` corresponding to the first string `s[i2]` such that `s[i2][1] == l2` and the first string `s[j2]` such that `s[j2][1] != l2`. Add j2-i2 to the answer.
3. Repeat this procedure n times, until you run out of letters in the original string. The answer to the problem is j1-i1 + j2-i2 + ... + jn-in

Answer (score 1):

You mention in the comments that it is correct, but it's very slow.

In Java, you can get the length of a `String` with `s.length()` - this value is cached in the object and it is `O(1)` to get.

But when you go to C, you get the length of a string with `strlen(s)` which recalculates (in `O(n)`) each time. So while you should be doing `O(n)`, because you have an `O(n)` operation in there, the entire function becomes `O(n^2)`.

To get around this, cache the value once when you run it. This will bring you back into linear time.

Bad:

```
scanf("%s",s);
for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
    if(s[i]==s[0])
    {
        sum=sum+getSim(s,i);
    }
```

Good:

```
scanf("%s",s);
strlen = strlen(s); /* assume you declared "int strlen" earlier */
for(i=0;i<strlen;i++) /* this is now constant time to run */
    if(s[i]==s[0])
    {
        sum=sum+getSim(s,i);
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't give linear time for input with high similarity, the `getSim()` can also be O(n). Consider the case of `memset(str, 'a', n)`.

Comment: @Daniel fair enough. I don't actually know his algorithm's current time. I was under the assumption that it was `O(n)` because this just seems like (call it programmer intuition) something that's done in `O(n)` time. Whatever his current time is, he can decrease it by a factor of `n` with the trick described above.

Comment: Only if the work done inside the loop is O(1). It's of course always a good thing to calculate `strlen()` only once. That gets you from O(n*(n + body)) to O(n*body), but if `body` is O(n) too, it's a constant factor reduction, if `body` is O(n^2), it's peanuts, if `body` is O(sqrt(n)) it's a reduction by a factor of sqrt(n).

Comment: @Daniel ummm not exactly peanuts. If body is `O(n^2)` then without caching strlen your total is `O(n^3)`. Going from cubic to quadratic is a HUGE increase in speed. In fact, the less efficient the body is, the better increase the cache gives. No matter what, it's always a factor of `n`.

Comment: No. Say `body` is `sum += strlen(s);`. Without caching you have two `strlen()` calls per iteration, with caching you have one. You're not multiplying the cost of `body` with the cost of `strlen()`, you're adding them.

Comment: @Daniel That's just inaccurate. The `strlen(s)` calculation is in the `for` loop. That means it's going to get calculated `n` times... With caching, you have `0` calls to `strlen` each iteration. As a general rule, if a string remains unmodified, you should never have to calculate its length more than once.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6745/discussion-between-daniel-fischer-and-glowcoder)

Comment: I absolutely agree with the last sentence. But if the body is `sum += strlen(s);` then we calculate `strlen(s)` twice for each index, makes 2*n times for a total 2*n*n cost. If we move the `strlen(s)` calculation out of the loop header, but have the body unmodified, we call `strlen(s)` a total of (n+1) times, once for the precalculation and once for each index. Total (n+1)*n cost.

Comment: If that were that case you could just as easily use the cached value inside the body of the loop as well... Regardless I don't see what bearing that has on the question, since `strlen` isn't inside the body...

Comment: No, but `getSim(s,i)` has complexity up to `n - i`, the `strlen` was just a simple example of an O(n) thing in the loop body. The cost of a loop iteration is O(cost(condition) + cost(body) + cost(update)). If cost(body) is worse than cost(condition), reducing the condition cost to O(1) doesn't give you much. If both have the same complexity, you get a constant factor speedup.

Comment: @Daniel sorry your formula of `O(cost(condition) + cost(body) + cost(update))` isn't accurate. It's more like `O(cost(for loop) * cost(getSim()))`. No matter what the cost of the `getSim()` function is, the cost of the program is `n * cost(getSim())` right now because of the `strlen()` in the `for` loop. Currently, `getSim()` operates in `O(i)` which is `O(strlen(s))`. So my assessment of the operation of going from `O(n^2)` to `O(n)` is accurate.

Comment: I've added the code to my answer, run it if you don't believe me. It's not a factor of 100000, but of 2, more or less. Of course, it's specially tailored so that the loop body has cost `n - i`, for normal strings the cost of `getSim` would be O(1) or O(small) on average, then moving the `strlen` out of the loop condition would gain a factor of n (or close).